# Why can't I use Regex to evaluate if...else statement

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use regex to evaluate whether the `newArray` at index 0 is equivalent to the value stored in `vowel`. I know that this method doesn't work but I don't understand why.
BTW I've just started learning how to code so I only really know Vanilla JS

```
function translate(val) {
    let newArray = Array.from(val)
    let vowel = /^[aeiouy]/gi
    let consonant = /[^aeiouy]/
    if (newArray[0] == vowel) {
        return 'vowel';
    } else if (newArray[0] == consonant) {
        return 'consonant'
    } {
        return 'none';
    }
}
 translate('inglewood')
```

Comment: Is `Array.from(var)` supposed to be `Array.from(val)`?

Comment: Yes! just fixed that @ThumChoonTat

Comment: `newArray[0] == consonant` that's not how regex's are used ... use String .match or RegExp .test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the regex `test` method here:

```js
function translate(val) {
    let vowel = /^[aeiouy]/gi;
    let consonant = /^[^aeiouy]/;
    if (vowel.test(val)) {
        return 'vowel';
    } else if (consonant.test(val)) {
        return 'consonant'
    } else {
        return 'none';
    }
}

console.log(translate('inglewood'));
```

Note: I don't see any point in using `Array.from()` here.  Instead, we can just run `test` directly against an input string.

Comment: Thank you! This will actually make the next steps so much easier for me code!

Answer (score 0):

You need to `.test()` the string with the regex

```js
function translate(val) {
    let newArray = Array.from(val)
    let vowel = /^[aeiouy]/gi
    let consonant = /[^aeiouy]/

    if ( vowel.test( newArray[0] ) ) {
        return 'vowel';
    } else if ( consonant.test( newArray[0] ) ) {
        return 'consonant'
    } {
        return 'none';
    }
}
console.log( translate('inglewood') );
```